# Free live online English assessment test for IELT/TOEFL

Tags: ielts

Is there any online website/service which lets you assess the level of your English for IELTS/TOEFL for free or free trial offer. Please advice

Comment: Welcome to ELL Dave - Requests for recommendations of websites or software are not on topic for ELL. You may find the [Resources for learning English](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/735/) thread on our meta site helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that any free online test is going to give you a good indication of your strength in the English language.

I would say that it is worth looking for past papers on these tests (with answers, try searching for `sample tests`) and completing them, and then seeing how you score afterward. If you can't find answers, it might be worth finding someone fluent or who teaches English to mark them for you.

Good luck!